# Reinforcement learning in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to do a model of reinforcement learning but I can't get my turtles to hatch correctly. Here's how the program is meant to work.

To start, a state is chosen at random. This is the state-class. Then a turtle with this state-class is chosen at random. Next a turtle with an act-class that is the same breed as the previous turtle is chosen. The value of the act-class is compared to the value of the state-class to determine the payoff. Finally hatch payoff many turtles of the first kind and payoff many turtles of the second kind.

My problem is that an arbitrary number of turtles of random kinds are being hatched. Any idea what's wrong with my code?

```netlogo
to go
ask turtles[let state random 4 
let category one-of turtles with [state-class = state]
ifelse [category1?] of category 
[let act1 one-of category1 with [act?]
ifelse state = [act-class] of act1 
[set payoff 4]      
[ifelse (state = 0 or state = 3) and ([act-class] of act1 = 1 or [act-class] of act1 = 2)     
[set payoff 3]         
[ifelse ([act-class] of act1 = 1 or [act-class] of act1 = 2) and (state = 1 or state = 4)       
[set payoff 3]       
[set payoff 1]]]    

hatch-category1 1 * payoff [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor set state-class state
                                set state? true set act? false 
                                set color [color] of category] 

hatch-category1 1 * payoff [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
                                set act-class [act-class] of act1
                                set state? false set act? true
                                set color [color] of act1]]

[let act2 one-of category2 with [act?]

ifelse state = [act-class] of act2       
[set payoff 4]

[ifelse (state = 0 or state = 3) and ([act-class] of act2 = 1 or [act-class] of act2 = 2)          
[set payoff 3]          
[ifelse ([act-class] of act2 = 1 or [act-class] of act2 = 2) and (state = 1 or state = 4)

[set payoff 3]            
[set payoff 1]]]

hatch-category2 1 * payoff [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor set state-class state
                                set state? true set act? false 
                                set color [color] of category]

hatch-category1 1 * payoff [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
                               set act-class [act-class] of act2
                               set state? false set act? true
                               set color [color] of act2]]]  
tick
end
```

Comment: Lindley, welcome to StackOverflow.  Here's some advice: The first thing to do is to try write a version of your program that's simplified so that everything that's irrelevant to the problem is gone.  There are a few reasons to do this.  First, it's not right to expect others to filter your code to find the location of the problem.  Second, in the process of simplifying your code, you'll often discover the problem on your own. For example, if your problem has to do with the number of turtles being hatched, then try to get rid of all lines that don't affect the hatching of turtles.